# Trying to eco specific date from DB but nothing is displaying

Tags: php, mysql

[image: complete query]

I have a DB table as follows. I am trying to display latest available date in a DIV with  using below mentioned php query but nothing is displayed. What am i doing wrong. Rest all is working fine. Only "< h3 >" part is not.

**Particular Query**

Intentionally placing spaces in h3 opening/closing tags and before ?php for displaying here.

```
<h3><?php echo $program->rating_date = ("max(rating_date) from wpsk_youtube_programs") ?> </h3>
```

**DB Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `wpsk_youtube_programs` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `channel_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `channel_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `program_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `program_name` varchar(54) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `episode_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `episode_thumbnail_link` varchar(74) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `rank_order_extra` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `episode_video_link` varchar(73) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `publish_date` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `youtube_likes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `youtube_dislikes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `youtube_views` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `youtube_comments` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `youtube_total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rank_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `insertID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Section HTML**

attached in image

[image]

Comment: _"Particular Query"_ - Where's the rest of the query and where/when do you execute it? All the posted code does is storing a string in a class property.

Comment: i missed the attachment now s attached

Comment: Don't post images of code. All code _must_ be copied into the question itself. Also, your question (and code) is super unclear. What are you expecting that echo in your h3 to actually output when you're just echoing when setting a class property? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.